# How to generate DNS for GCP cloud sql private ip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I've been trying to set up a Kubernetes cluster with Google Cloud SQL with a private IP connection with Terraform scripts in Google cloud. These terraform scripts work perfectly fine. Then I rollup Kubernetes configuration with deployments, services, and pods that use this database private IP. The problem that Terraform scripts creates Database with a random private IP each time when it got created. So it is very inconvenient to set up the IP in Kubernetes configuration manually. Is there any way to generate private DNS for this private IP and use it in the Kubernetes configuration?

I tried to create a private DNS zone and assign a record pointing to Cloud SQL private IP. But it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Don't use IP addresses. Use Cloud SQL Proxy instead. The proxy uses the instance name instead of IP addresses. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine

Comment: In regards to your question about using DNS for private IP addresses, post the details on how you configured the "private zone" for Cloud DNS. Include details on how you are accessing the private zone, as in the actual command showing the hostname that you are trying to resolve.

Comment: Jonh, thanks for the question. During the exercise of a description I found that here is a severla options how you can create a dns. I will update main post with the soultion.

Comment: Don't do that. Roll back your edit and post the solution as an answer instead. Then accept your answer to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: change in a way you advised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any proper way to do it in GCP.

**Updated solution that works for me**

DNS zone and record set were created by a command below

```
gcloud beta dns --project=project-name managed-zones create private-db-zone --description= --dns-name=db.test.com. --visibility=private --networks project-network-dev

gcloud dns --project=project-name record-sets transaction start --zone=private-db-zone

gcloud dns --project=project-name record-sets transaction add 10.116.0.3 --name=private.db.test.com. --ttl=300 --type=A --zone=private-db-zone

gcloud dns --project=project-name record-sets transaction execute --zone=private-db-zone
```

Comment: I thought you were after a Terraform-based solution though?  And this isn't that.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Terraform. Just replace internal.example.org with whatever domain you want to use. Also make sure you have permissions to admin Cloud DNS.

```
resource "google_dns_managed_zone" "private_zone" {
  name        = "private-zone"
  dns_name    = "internal.*example*.org."
  description = "Internal DNS zone"

  visibility = "private"

  private_visibility_config {
    networks {
      network_url = module.vpc.network_self_link
    }
  }
}

resource "google_dns_record_set" "db_dns" {
  depends_on = [google_dns_managed_zone.private_zone]
  managed_zone = google_dns_managed_zone.private_zone.name
  name = "db.${google_dns_managed_zone.private_zone.dns_name}"
  rrdatas = [google_sql_database_instance.instance.private_ip_address]
  ttl = 300
  type = "A"
}
```